# Identity Server 4 with .NET Core 3.1 -- Identity Server returning token as null

Tags: .net-core, identityserver4, .net-core-3.1

My project is based on Identity Server 4 (2.0.0) with .NET Core 2.0, and everything is working fine.

But when I migrate it to Identity Server 4 (3.1.4) with .NET Core 3.1, Identity Server is returning the token as null. I am using a Resourceownerpasswordcredentials grant, which was working with earlier versions.

The Identity store used is DynamoDB from AWS.

How can I debug and find out the issue?